# MSMQ QMThreadNo on Server

Tags: .net, msmq, nservicebus

In an attempt to optimise the performance of MSMQ on my server machine I have upped the QMThreadNo, however i am not noticing any difference in performance (have tried both increasing and decreasing the number).

I am restarting Messaging service on each registry change.

*Server: Windows 2008 R2 box, 4GB RAM, Intel Xeon X5670 @ 2.93 (2 processors)*

Comment: Have you increased the number of worker threads in NServiceBus?

Comment: MSMQ is already optimised for most common scenarios. Have you performed any performance analysis (disk/CPU/memory/network)? Which specific bottleneck are you trying to remove?

Comment: the server isn't struggling at all when i have looked at the performance. bottleneck occurs when i have a large amount of inactive outgoing queues with messages waiting to be sent. The outgoing queues that are for clients that are online are not getting processed fast enough.

Answer (score 1):

The solution i ended up using was to pause inactive outgoing queues using [this](http://intellecting.net/blog/post/MSMQ-Outgoing-Queues.aspx) extension library. No processing time is spent on paused outgoing queues, so it doesn't waste its time trying to resolve to the offline client queues. derr.